# How to call the function when user click outside of dialog box

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have Alert Dialog box and I've a button that say "Got it" to deactivate the Alert Dialog so that it stop showing when a user revisit the site.

My Alert Dialog box also close when ever a user click outside the dialog box so I'm wondering how to apply above action when a user click outside of the dialog to close the alert dialog box and stop showing when the user revisit the site.

so this is what I'm trying to do

User click outside alert dialog -> close alert dialog -> deactivate Alert Dialog (call gotIt() function )

Dialog Box HTMl

```
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [style.marginRight.px]="20" (click)="gotIt()" matTooltip="Close">Got
            it!</button>
```

```
  gotIt() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.notifications.length; index++) {
      const notification = this.notifications[index];
      if (notification && notification.userNotification) {
        notification.userNotification.isDismissed = 1;
        notification.userNotification.isUnread = 0;
      }
    }
    this.notificationService.updateUserNotification(this.notifications).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.dialogRef.close()
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `hostListener` to listen to the event like this

```
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) click($event){
    // here you can hide your menu
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```